# why is my loop not working properly visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner in vb and I am to display an * for every 100 in stores sales; However, in the loop is reprinting the value enter before. thanks for any help.

I want to add to the list as follow:

- store 1: **
- store 2 *****

Every * = 100

```
Public Class Exercise6

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        Const intNumberOfDays As Integer = 5           'days 
        Dim intSales As Decimal = 0             'to hold daily sales
        Dim strUserInput As String              'to hold user input
        Dim strAsterisks As String = ""          'Asterisks
        Const intAsterisk As Integer = 100
        Dim intAsteriskTotal As Integer
        Dim strDataOut As String = String.Empty    'holds the list output
        Dim intCounter As Integer = 1

        'gets sales for 5 stores
        Do While intCounter <= intNumberOfDays
            strUserInput = InputBox("Enter the sales for store" &
                                    intCounter.ToString(), "Store Sales is Needed")
            If strUserInput <> String.Empty And IsNumeric(strUserInput) Then
                intSales = CInt(strUserInput)


                'calculate the number of asterisk that must be display
                intAsteriskTotal = CInt(intSales / intAsterisk)

                strAsterisks = New String(CChar("*"), intAsteriskTotal)
                'add the store to the output string


                strDataOut &= "Store " & intCounter.ToString() & ": " & strAsterisks
                'add the output to the list box
                lstChart.Items.Add(strDataOut)
                intCounter += 1
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a proper value for store sales.")
            End If

        Loop

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem in your code is that you are appending the string in each iteration to the `strDataOut` using `strDataOut &=`. so it will be correct if you clear the `strDataOut` on the starting of the loop `strDataOut = ""`. hence your code will be like the following :

```
    Do While intCounter <= intNumberOfDays
        strUserInput = InputBox("Enter the sales for store" &
                                intCounter.ToString(), "Store Sales is Needed")
        strDataOut = "" '<---------- Additional line added
        If strUserInput <> String.Empty And IsNumeric(strUserInput) Then
            intSales = CInt(strUserInput)
            intAsteriskTotal = CInt(intSales / intAsterisk)
            strAsterisks = New String(CChar("*"), intAsteriskTotal)
            strDataOut &= "Store " & intCounter.ToString() & ": " & strAsterisks
            ListBox1.Items.Add(strDataOut)
            intCounter += 1
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a proper value for store sales.")
        End If
    Loop
```

Answer (score -1):

Just fixed. I changed

```
strDataOut &= "Store " & intCounter.ToString() & ": " & strAsterisks
```

with

```
strDataOut = "Store " & intCounter.ToString() & ": " & strAsterisks
```